# how to request where object like somethingnot case sensitive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use a request so I m looking on how to make it not case sensitive

```
perso=# select count(ref) from media where titre like '%WAR%' ;
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)

perso=# select count(ref) from media where titre like '%war%' ;
 count
-------
    19
(1 row)

perso=#
```

currently I do :

```
perso=# select count(ref) from media where titre like '%war%' or titre like '%WAR%' ;
 count
-------
    19
(1 row)

perso=#
```

Is there a better methode or syntax  ?

Comment: `ILIKE`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: 3 options, use `LOWER` or `UPPER` before pattern matching, use `ILIKE`, change the type of media to be CITEXT,

Comment: Ah thanks the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE page is exactly what I need & didn't frind (thanks Haleemur Ali too for the "type" method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ILIKE`. It is the same as `LIKE`, only case insensitive.